# Post-synthesis simulation: Loading a custom standard cell library to a verilog compiler

Tags: simulation, synthesis

I have a synthesized (gate level) netlist, and the cells that were provided to the synthesizer are part of a standard cell library I characterized on my own, out of transistor-level (post-layout) spice netlists.

How do I go about performing a post-synthesis simulation?
I have a .lib file, .lef file and the synthesized (gate-level) netlist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Every simulator has a tool guide. Search in there. It will be there as TCL commands. If it's not there, dump that simulator.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I went through a lot of user guides, Verilog simulators do NOT allow us to load a standard cell library in their .lib format. We need to translate them to a .v file with the delay information, that's the only way it can be done. I'll leave this here as an answer as well, it might help someone else looking for the same thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilog simulators usually do NOT allow you to load a standard cell library in their .lib for usage.

If you used a tool like Cadence Liberate for charecterization of the standard cell library, then you can do

`write_verilog -specparams -table_style min-avg-max libname.v`

You need to have the .v file for the library. Once you have this, you can compile them in the right order.

Library, then the design, then the testbench.